# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n \arctan\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) $

Tags: calculus, limits

This question is from an old preliminary exam for my college's master degree, and I am doing old questions for prepare the exam which is coming soon, but I totally have no idea to solve this question. 
Please help me to solve it. Thank you very much.

Calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n \arctan\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) .$$

Comment: Consider to compare it with the integral of arctan in [0,1]

Comment: Have you heard about Riemann sums?

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you guys very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given limit is equal to
$$
\int_0^1 \arctan x dx.
$$
Then by integration by parts,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \arctan x dx &= [x\arctan x]_0^1 -\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4} - \left[\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2)\right]_0^1\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases}u=\arctan x&u'=\frac1{1+x^2}\\v'=1&v=x\end{cases}\;\;\implies \int\arctan x\,dx=x\arctan x-\int\frac x{1+x^2}dx=$$

$$=x\arctan x-\frac12\log(1+x^2)+K$$